# How to access child id's inside a id from a website using Selenium + Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract data from `https://corpus.byu.edu/iweb/`
when I'm trying to access the search bar present in search tab, Python + Selenium is giving a NoElement found exception. When I tried to print all elements by id on the website, I got only one element called 'myFrames'.
How can I access the elements which are present in myFrames?
'p' is the id of the search bar present in search tab of the website.
I tried the following:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="p"]')

browser.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="p"]')

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="p"]')

WebDriverWait(browser, 
20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.xpath,'//div[@id="p"]')))
```

I was not able to access the element by any of these. How can I access the element with id 'p'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) First you need to switch to the frame:

```
browser.switch_to.frame("x1")
```

2) Do actions inside the frame.

3) Switch back to the main window:

```
browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: no such frame: element is not a frame

Comment: @venkatesh.b, I have updated my answer -- try again.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in switching the frame.

Comment: Worked for me.Thank you so much.I wasted my time since morning doing this

Comment: You are welcome! @venkatesh.b, check a tick near my answer, please. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah.But Iam new to stackoverflow.So it says "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded but donot change the publicly displayed score"

Comment: @venkatesh.b, nope, this is a tick under down arrow (not votes (up and down arrow)).

Comment: @venkatesh.b, just click on this tick. Thanks.